# Is there any way to get CRF loss in using Tensorflow addons

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have used "from tensorflow_addons.layers import CRF" for the CRF implementation in TensorFlow. I am familiar with the way around using Keras contrib library but I was wondering how did tf didn't make any implementation of crf loss in tf 2?

Comment: Because this CRF doesn't have loss function. AttributeError: 'CRF' object has no attribute 'loss_function'

Comment: Did you figure this out?